# Why can't I seem to keep a reliable connection when utilizing two adapters?

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, network-adapter

I'm currently in an interesting situation.  All of my computers are connected to a wifi network (which has an internet connection).  Connecting to that is easy enough.  In my room I also have a local network between my computers.  While they all have a valid connection the wifi, while connected through the LAN, all of the computers flip out.  Basically, they'll drop the internet connection occasionally, won't connect to the wifi while connected to the LAN, etc.

What is going on?  Why in the world can none of my computers handle connections on two different adapters?  Is there some way I can fix this?

There doesn't seem to be any environmental factors affecting my setup - it only drops the connection on occasion, when I'm connected to both - one or the other is perfectly fine.

My desktop is running Windows 7 and my Laptop is running Windows 8.  There are other machines on the network as well, but they're also Windows machines which makes me believe that listing them all out would have no bearing on the problem.

Comment: 1) Which OS? 2) Is your system using a network manager which switches to the *best* network and disables the alternative?  (Which kind of makes sense on a laptop with both wired and wireless, but which is a PITA on a desktop).

Comment: Have you noticed if there is any WiFi interference when this happens? I've experienced a wireless mouse drop a WiFi connection and have notice when the microwave is run the wireless drops...

Comment: One OS is Windows 7 (the desktop) and the other is Windows 8 (my laptop).